# Using databricks dbutils in spark submit (Scala) - Null pointer exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks, dbutils

Im trying to use dbutils in scala spark. Im submitting this job on databricks using spark submit. But, Im getting null pointer exception.

```
import com.databricks.dbutils_v1.DBUtilsHolder.dbutils

try{
   val s3_ls = dbutils.fs.ls(targetS3Dir)
}
catch{
   case e: Exception =>
   logger.error(e)
}
```

I have added the following dependancy in build.sbt,

```
"com.databricks" %% "dbutils-api" % "0.0.4"
```

Im even adding ***com.databricks:dbutils-api:0.0.4*** in ***--packages*** in spark-submit.

Im building a jar and passing it in the spark submit command. Im still getting the null pointer exception error.

Is there anything Im missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that `targetS3Dir` is not null? Provide full exception message / stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This library is just a placeholder so you can compile your code locally (and you need to mark this dependency as `provided`), but it doesn't contain actual code. You don't need to include it when submitting a job, because this jar is a part of the Databricks Runtime.